# How to wait for N seconds between statements in Scala?

Tags: scala, sleep

I have two statements like this:

```
val a = 1
val b = 2
```

In between the 2 statements, I want to pause for N seconds like I can in `bash` with `sleep` command.

Answer (score 117, accepted):

You can try:

```
val a = 1 
Thread.sleep(1000) // wait for 1000 millisecond
val b = 2
```

You can change 1000 to other values to accommodate to your needs.

Answer (score 11):

Given:

```
package object wrap {
  import java.time._

  def delayed[A](a: => A): A = {
    Console println Instant.now
    Thread.sleep(1000L)
    val x = a
    Console println Instant.now
    x
  }
}
```

You can:

```
Welcome to Scala 2.12.0-M3 (Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM, Java 1.8.0_60).
Type in expressions for evaluation. Or try :help.

scala> $intp.setExecutionWrapper("wrap.delayed")

scala> { println("running"); 42 }
2016-02-20T06:28:17.372Z
running
2016-02-20T06:28:18.388Z
res1: Int = 42

scala> :quit
```